# Make image link to next page jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, image, mobile

Im working on my first jquery mobile app.
So.. i have every page in one HTML file, using data-roles.
Now, my problem is linking an image to a next page. When i ad a standard button it will link to the page i am referring to with #somepage.
But now i have added an image and i want that image to link to the next page when somebody clicks on it.
Can somebody please tell me why it does not work?

```
<div data-role="page id="home">
    <div data-role="header" id="header" data-position="fixed">
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" id="content">


    <a href="#calculator" > <img src="images/taximeter.png" id="taximeter"> </a>


    </div>



   <div data-role="footer" data-position-"fixed">


       <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home" class="ui-bar-a"> Home </a></li>
            <li><a href="#instellingen" class="ui-bar-a"> Instellingen </a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact" class="ui-bar-a"> Contact </a></li>
            </ul>
       </div>
</div>
```

```
<!---Calculator page -->

<div data-role="page" id="calculator">
     <div data-role="header" >
        <h1> Calculator</h1>
     </div>

     <div data-role="content">
     </div>

     <div data-role="footer">
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: put calculator page name (calculator.html for example) into href property

Comment: When i put calculator.html and i click on the image it says 'error loading page'.. When i put #calculator like above it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify the file name in href when you want load another page w/o #
i.e

```
<a href="calculator.html">link</a>
```

you can use the href=#calculator if you have the page in same html file like

```
<div data-role=page id=current_page>
<a href="#calculator">link</a>
</div>

<div data-role=page id=calculator>
//page content
</div>
```